# How to design around multiple inheritance in java when using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

All objects might have certain common features such as editable (in which case they'd have attributes edited by and edit date), create-able (in which case they'd have attributes created by and create date), and more.

Using interfaces is pointless because every field, getter, and setter would have to be re-declared.

Using abstract class is impossible because if they need to extend from 2 or 3 of them, they can't

Using composition doesn't seem possible because in Hibernate you're supposed to have each field map to a thing in the database; if it doesn't map to the database you can declare "transient" but then it might be impossible or a headache to get the fields *within* the fields to associate with columns.

Comment: You are looking for `@Embeddable` and `@Embedded`.

Comment: Or eventually AspectJ inter-type declarations, not to declare the fields on any class using interfaces, but that's maybe overkill.